# Concat sql sum in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to use the `sum` yield in `group_concat` or any work around?

I have the following query, which returns redundant results for for `item_id` and `items.title` fields:

```
SELECT
  item_id, sum(qty), items.title, units.title
  FROM invoice_items
  LEFT JOIN items
   ON item_id = items.id
    LEFT JOIN units ON invoice_items.unit_id = units.id
 GROUP BY item_id, invoice_items.unit_id ORDER BY items.id, units.weight DESC;
```

I tried to use `group_concat` to concat redundant rows as follows:

```
SELECT
sum(qty),  group_concat(item_id, items.title, sum(qty) SEPARATOR '-')
  FROM invoice_items
  LEFT JOIN items
   ON item_id = items.id
    LEFT JOIN units ON invoice_items.unit_id = units.id
 GROUP BY item_id, invoice_items.unit_id ORDER BY items.id, units.weight DESC;
```

However, it returns this error: `Invalid use of group function`

What I want is to concatenate the `sum` yield in one row regard less of any other fields.

The following is a screen shot for the query result:

[image]

I need first row to be something like:

```
item_id: 1
sum(qty): 2, 13, 5
title: اسبوسيد أقراص
```

Comment: General GROUP BY tip: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: I guess removing `invoice_items.unit_id` from `group by` will fix the problem. Why have you used `invoice_items.unit_id` in `group by`

Comment: `sum()` result is only available after all the relevant rows/groups have been discovered, which means it's NOT available at the time mysql is starting to concatenate the rows it's finding.

Comment: @MarcB I will try sub select for sum.

Comment: alternatively, you could concat in some sentinel value, e.g. `**SUMGOESHERE**` and then do a string replacement on the eventual concatted result, and substitute in your sum() value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do another `group by` using your query (with appropriate column names as a subquery):

```
SELECT item_id, title, GROUP_CONCAT(sumqty)
FROM (SELECT ii.item_id, sum(qty) as sumqty, i.title
      FROM invoice_items ii LEFT JOIN
           items i
           ON ii.item_id = i.id LEFT JOIN
           units u
           ON ii.unit_id = u.id
     GROUP BY ii.item_id, ii.unit_id
    ) ii
GROUP BY item_id;
```

Comment: Excellent! It works so fine, However, I wonder, where is `AS` keyword!
Thank you very much

Comment: This is a screen shot of the result of this great query: [here](http://imgur.com/34kYI8A)

Comment: I mean how could we use `i` and `ii` without regarding `as`?

Comment: The `AS` keyword is *optional* when assigning a table alias. My preference is to always omit the `AS` keyword for a *table* alias. That's informed mostly by my experience with other databases, such as Oracle, which prohibit the `AS` keyword in that context. (When assigning an alias to a *column*, the `AS` keyword is also optional. My preference is to always include the `AS` keyword when assigning an alias to a column.) Gordon's query follows this same pattern.

Comment: @spencer7593 . . . You exactly capture the rules that I use.  Specifically, `as` for column aliases helps avoid the problem of missing commas (in the sense that `select col1 col2` doesn't look right because it should be either `select col1 as col2` or `select col1, col2`).  I haven't found any  use at all for `as` for table aliases.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: *exactly* my reasoning **`AS`** well. I do reserve the right to be anal about capitalizing keywords. One small quibble with your query, re-using the same table alias `ii`.  Once as for a table reference in the inline view, and again as the alias for the inline view. That's valid SQL. And the MySQL optimizer follows the rules. My personal preference is to not re-use a table alias within a statement.